# Does my World Clock have an Error (Time for Jameica/Kingston)

Tags: sony-xperia, 7.1-nougat, clock

So I am in Berlin and try to see the time of Jameica. Berlin is currently UTC+2, Jameica UTC-5 -> makes -7 difference.

I tried this around 11:30 local time, and expected 5:30, but what I got is 20:30.

What is going on there. Is it a bug? Or a feature?

In the adding screen it shoes GMT -5

[image]

The weather is nice - but the time wrong.

[image]

Settings seem right

[image]

And now the funny workaround part - if I choose another city in UTC-5 all works:

[image]

Same time as it would be right in Kingston - weather not so good:

[image]